# How to iterate elements by 5 : Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that is about 90 in length, I would like to iterate so that 5 objects at each iteration have different values, at each integration I do a print to see the elements, like this:

```
L= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
loop....
   print(first,second,third,fourth,fifth)
>>> "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" -> first iteration
>>> "f","g","h","i","j" -> second iteration
```

how can I proceed ?

Comment: sorry if I expressed myself badly but I do not seek to separate the list in two I seek to allocate the first element of the list to an object (first = "a"), the second to a second object etc... then to print it and the same objectc will have the next 5 values of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that length of the list a product of 5, then you can use the following

```py
for index in range(0,len(L),5):
    first=L[index]
    second=L[index+1]
    third=L[index+2]
    fourth=L[index+3]
    fifth=L[index+4]
    print(first,second,third,fourth,fifth)
```

If it isn't, and you want the rest fo to be printed too, then you can use the following code:

```py
for index in range(0,len(L),5):
    if index+5>len(L):
        print(" ".join(L[index:]))
    else:
        print(" ".join(L[index:index+5]))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't sure about the length of the `list` you can use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) then use `islice` like below:

```
import math
from itertools import cycle , islice
L = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]
i = cycle(L)
slc = 5
for _ in range(math.ceil(len(L)/slc)):
    print(list(islice(i,slc)))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['f', 'g', 'h', 'a', 'b']
```

If you sure about the length you can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and get what you want like below:

```
from itertools import islice
L = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
i = iter(L)
slc = 5
for _ in range(len(L)//slc):
    print(list(islice(i,slc)))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
L = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
for i in range(0, len(L), 5):
    print(L[i:i + 5])
```

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
```